# How to run OwinHost from non-bin folder?

Tags: asp.net, owin, katana

OwinHost.exe seems to only want to run against an application that lives in a folder called "bin". If I try against another folder e.g. "bin2", OwinHost says that it can't find the startup attribute.

I've tried running from within the bin2 folder, outside it, and tried the -d and -b arguments - nothing seems to work.